# How can i perform checking/unchecking with onclick="" in input type="checkbox"?

Tags: javascript

I have some checkboxes, and i want to have a chance to check/uncheck them with onclick="". For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="onOff();document.location.href='index.php?goto=somewhere';return false;" class="filter">
```

So if it is already checked, it should be unchecked and vice versa. What can be inside onOff() ? The goal is to make redirect with "goto" only if checkbox was checked. And is it was unchecked - redirect to "index.php" without "goto"

Comment: this is unclear : what about `document.location.href` it make your page lost and your checkbox disapear, as your `onOff()` action.

Answer (score 0):

> So if it is already checked, it should be unchecked and vice versa.

This already happens. It's just that your `return false;` in your `onclick` inline JS means that the default action (i.e. to uncheck - or check - the checkbox) will not be taken.

Just remove the `return false;` part. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const
  chkBxDirection = document.querySelector('#chkBx-direction')
, linkDirection  = chkBxDirection.nextElementSibling
, directions = 
    [ { href:'index.php?goto=somewhereOne', txt:'somewhere One direction' } 
    , { href:'index.php?goto=somewheretwo', txt:'somewhere Two direction' } 
    ];

chkBxDirection.checked = false // according to linkDirection init
chkBxDirection.onclick =_=>
  {
  let index                 = Number(chkBxDirection.checked)
  linkDirection.href        = directions[index].href
  linkDirection.textContent = directions[index].txt
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBx-direction">
<a href="index.php?goto=somewhereOne">somewhere One direction</a>
```